# Attempting to receive data from ajax call using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make an ajax call using jQuery to a test.php file but it is not returning any data. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#submit").click(function(){ 
    $.ajax({    
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://192.168.1.21/opencart1/upload/admin/view/template/module/test.php",
       data: $("#url").serialize(),
       success: function(msg) {
          alert(data);
          document.getElementById("pollcontent").innerHTML = msg;
       }
   }); 
 })
});  
        </script>


        <div class="content">
        <form id="theform">
          <input type="text" name="url" value="" id="url" />
          <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>
          </form>
          <div id="pollcontent"></div>
```

This is the test.php file:

```
<?php
$abc="hi";
echo $abc;
?>
```

Comment: You are alerting `data`. I think that you should be alerting `msg` as the response from the server.

Comment: Is it not returning _data_ in your `success`'s `alert(data)` statement or in the `document...` statement?

Comment: i also alert the msg but still not working

Comment: it is not returning the data in success's alert(data)

Comment: Right, `data` is not defined in the function. `msg` is the response from the server.

Comment: Might want to look into using the `error` callback in your $.ajax call to see if you're getting some sort of network error.  `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown); }`, something like that.  Just put that after your `success` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Change the success to the following.

```
success: function(msg) {
       alert(msg);
       document.getElementById("pollcontent").innerHTML = msg;
    }
```

`data` is not defined in the success function. You should use `msg` (or change `msg` to `data`)

Comment: Are you using the developer tools? Check the `Network` tab to see if there is a problem with the response from the server. Also check the `Console` to see if there are any Javascript errors.

Comment: i am not getting any error. i have checked in developers tools. i am working in opencart. am i doing right with ajax working ?

Comment: is this the way ajax is called in opencart

Comment: You should probably put a reference to `opencart` in your question. I am not familiar with `opencart`. Try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/kSqNF/) to see what I setup with the `$.ajax()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in the ajax request you are attempting to access url which is not of your domain or server ip. This is not valid for ajax requests.

Try your server url you will get success.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to POST to a remote server, which means you're going to need to allow Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) in your PHP response. This can easily be achieved by adding the an allow all CORS header:

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  $abc="hi";
  echo $abc;
?>
```